# React Navigation : back to top of stack but disable "BACK"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

[image: navigation flow map (Sorry, I cannot post image)]

I am using React Native for Android Application and React Navigation. Now at Screen 0 (`S0`). Then did following navigations.

1. `this.props.navigation.navigate("S1")`
2. `this.props.navigation.navigate("A1")`
3. `this.props.navigation.navigate("A2")`
4. `this.props.navigation.navigate("A3")`

Now, once Actions in A3 is done, I have to navigate back to Screen 1 (`S1`). However, if I use `this.props.navigation.navigate("S1")`, what happened is that I can Press Back button (hardware or Header bar) and it go back to Screen `A3`.

When the back button is pressed on `S1`, I want to go back to `S0`. I don't want to set it manually as well because many other pages can come to `S1`.

Any suggestions or ideas how to make this work? I have tried `popToTop()` and `goBack("A")` but both are not working.

Comment: I cannot answer you in detail because I am on the jump to leave office. But I achieved the same handling by using two different navigators. If this is not working you could try to manually change the navigator stack. This stack should be able to be accessed through this.props.navigation - By the way please insert which navigator you are using through the fact that there are several's out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NavigationActions.reset` to get back to your first screen or `NavigationActions.pop` to "pop" back to the screen you want.

**Sample code for nav reset**:

```
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [
                    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'S0' }),
                    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'S1' }),
                    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'A1' }),
                    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'A2' }),
                    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'A3' }),
            ],
    }));
```

**Sample code for nav pop:**

```
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.pop({
            n: 3,
            immediate: true
    }));
```

*Note: Remember to import { NavigationActions }*

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make this work by just

`this.props.navigation.pop(4)`. It will just back to 4th previous page and "Back" button still works as I intended. @Bryan 's suggestion works for me in one of the cases but I needed a much more general solution :D

Thank guys for helping! Really appreciate it.